# Loop through worksheets and copy value to range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through all worksheets (except the first two), copying a value from each one, and then placing the copied value into a column. This is what I have so far. It isn't giving me an error message, but it's also not working.

```
Sub copyGrades()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim grade As Double

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Student List").Range("H2:H174")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Rubric" And ws.Name <> "Student List" Then
            grade = ws.Range("E11").Value

            For Each rcell In rng.Cells
                rcell.Value = grade
            Next rcell

        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you define what exactly "isn't working" while the code technically works. What have you tried to design it to do? Right now you take one value from each worksheet and you fill the whole range with that one specific value. Right untill the very last worksheet. I can imagine this is not as intended, but then can you explain what it is that you wanted.

Comment: I think you've put your finger on the problem. I'm trying to place the first copied value into the first cell in the column, the the second copied value into the second cell, etc.But apparently that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: You don't need to loop through the `rng` to se the values. `rng.Value = grade` should work.

Comment: Do you have 172 Worksheets to copy from?

Comment: @Andras Dorko yes I have enough worksheets to copy from

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how I would do it (surely not the only way):

```
Option Explicit

Sub copyGrades()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim grade As Double
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim count As Integer

    count = 1
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Student List").Range("H2:H174")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Rubric" And ws.Name <> "Student List" Then
            grade = ws.Range("E11").Value
            rng.Cells(count, 1) = grade
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the nested loops to work, but I was able to solve it using another method (looking for a match between the worksheet name and the values in a given column).

```
Sub copyGrades()

    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Student List").Range("F2:F174")

            For Each rcell In rng.Cells

                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name = rcell.Value Then
                        rcell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ws.Range("E11").Value
                    End If
                Next ws

            Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: you seem to see the nested loops way as if it was absolutely necessary...